# How can a vortex be created?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity, vortex

i have seen this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnbJEg9r1o8&t=96s
It is not completly clear how a difference of velocity can cause a vortex, can you explain me?

Comment: Reminded me about this comedy segment about toroidal vortexes (with reference to original paper): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bcr9-93wXng

Comment: How much background in fluid mechanics and tensor algebra do you have?

Comment: Pretty good....

Comment: You must know that the motion at a point in a flow is the sum of translation, (rigid body) rotation, and straining (see [this](https://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~meam302/Chapter6.pdf)). Rotation part is vorticity.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of effects causing that. As she explained, the water flows off & around the edge of the plate, to the back, causing the ring of water around the plate to spin. Also, if there is a moving fluid against a stationary (or slower moving) fluid, the bit in between gets rolled between the two, like rolling a stick between your hands.